# load testing using multithreading for a spring rest ful webservice

Tags: spring, rest, load-testing

I had implemented a `restful service`. I want to do a load testing for spring rest ful service. In this i want to check how many users can access a service. How to do that..Please provide me some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of tools out there you can use for load testing. I've found [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to be a pretty robust open source option. Specifically for REST requests you can use the HTTP Request component.

That said, I'd be curious to hear what others are using.

Comment: thanks for your response, but is there any chance of do it as programatically??

Comment: Yes it was working for me @JJensL...But is there any chance to do it as programmatically. If you have any idea on that, please share me the information.